# Model has_many of anothe model ( Set of predefind values )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have two models, `Rating` & `RatingReason`, `RatingReason` will contain a list of static values that may increase with time.

```
class Rating < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :rating_reasons
end

class RatingReason < ApplicationRecord

end
```

but this doesn't work it says that i have to add `rating_id` on `RatingReason` model, but i don't think it's correct or that's not what i need to do, how can i acheive Rating has_many RatingReason without adding `rating_id` to `RatingReason` && get `rating_reason_ids`?

Comment: Why don't you think that's correct?

Comment: because RatingReason contains now 5 rows only, and i need for every rating to know what user selected from them, i don't care & don't need RatingReason

Comment: I think you need to backup a few steps and learn how [assocations work](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) and then decide if you are that is even what you need in the first place. You can't have a an association between two records without storing the foreign keys somewhere. But this question seems very much like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: They're known now, but may increase with time, I know Enum, but i don't think it's the best solution for my case.

Comment: If you want to do this then you can achieve by implementing like this :-  **belongs_to :rating, optional: true** put this association in RatingReason model.

Comment: Sounds like you need a join table and a has_many through relationship